# Extracting first line of multiple txt documents and saving as metadata/vector in R

Tags: r, metadata, text-analysis

I'm new to R and currently working with the quanteda-package for text analyis. For topic models over time I need metadata on the txt files I'm working with. The first line of each of my documents contains a date which I would like to extract in a fashion that it is linked to the document. 
I am able to extract the date from the first line of the document, which is structured as follows 
"date:23/04/1980"
 by using the following code:

```
fileName <- "C:/Users/fischer/project/_Los_Angeles_Times_The_New_York_Times_The_Was2018-01-14_01-01.txt"
mytxt <- readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size)
regmatches(extracted_texts, regexec("date:",extracted_texts))
date<-regmatches(extracted_texts, gregexpr(
  "date:[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}", extracted_texts))
```

R returns 
"date:23/04/1980"

What I can not achieve, is applying this to multiple documents in my directory and saving the output as a variable/vector which allows me to use it as metadata  for the functions of the quenteda package.

Answer (score 0):

You may find one option to do what you want below. Depending on the number and size of your documents, you might have to process the documents sequentially and cannot store them at once in a list. If below approach does not work for you, I cann provide you with an alternative.

```
# create some sample docs and write them in the working directory as txt files
docs = list(
  doc1 = c("abc2000", "def")
  ,doc2 = c("ghi2001", "jkl")
  ,doc3 = c("mno2002", "pqr")
)
for (i in names(docs)) {
  writeLines(docs[[i]], paste0(i, ".txt"))
}
# read the documents with the specified doc name into a list
# use list.files with a pattern for this, maybe with fullnames = TRUE in your case
# you can use the side effect of sapply/USE.NAMES, to generate a named list
# you might set n = 1 in readLines to only read the first line
# since you probably read in the full document at a certain point in your code
# here the full text example is read in
docs = sapply(list.files(pattern = "^doc\\d.txt$"), readLines, USE.NAMES = T, simplify = F)
# then access the first element of each list and apply your extraction function
# as an example I simply extract digits
lapply(docs, function(x) {
  first_line = x[1]
  gsub("\\D", "", first_line)
})
# $`doc1.txt`
# [1] "2000"
# 
# $doc2.txt
# [1] "2001"
# 
# $doc3.txt
# [1] "2002"
```